# How do I suppress MySQL errors?

Tags: mysql

I have an issue where our database is receiving ~1000 updates a minute, and often we get an error response:

```
TAF: 1297 (HY000) at line 1: Got temporary error 899 'Rowid already allocated' from NDBCLUSTER
```

which appears in our application to our customer.

Is there any way to suppress these errors at the MySQL level? As I am not the developer of this application, I am not sure what language is performing the updates, but I presume either shell script or a C program.

I am using MySQL: 5.1.44-ndb-7.1.3-cluster-log (2 cluster nodes and 1 cluster mgmt node)

Comment: It depends on how your customer is interfacing with mysql. Terminal window? Custom web app? Something else?

Comment: It appears in your application? You can suppress error reporting in your application by changing the error reporting handling in your application, no? And don't these error messages have something to tell you? Why do you want to suppress them?

Comment: This specific error is related to usage logging, but the front-end is in multiple languages and applications (PHP, Visual Basic, XML etc etc) So I'd like to suppress directly from MySQL and not the calling application. Why I want to suppres? Because it's a known issue with MySQL: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56051

Comment: That bug report has got some valid points, for example:  You need to trap this in your application and redo the failed transaction.  It does look like you are hitting this bug indeed.  That would be the correct workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the 'IGNORE' clause in your SQL statements, the documentation for this is [here](http://mysqlserverteam.com/improvements-to-the-mysql-ignore-implementation/)

Using the IGNORE clause will downgrade errors to warnings, these warnings are displayed using the 'SHOW WARNINGS;' command